# Table of data want to group, transpose matching values same line

Tags: vba, transpose

I have a table of data in Excel. Column A contains Names, Column B contains their interest. Each interest has a separate row. I want to take the data from this table and have a single row with the name of the customer and a column for each of their interests.  IE RAW Data:

[image]

I am looking to take the 4000 row table and grouping by the name. I am unsure how many times each name appears in the list (Once or Fifty times) but I want the interests placed on a single row with each interest in a separate column EG Desired Data:

[image]

I have tried the standard transpose....html table....and pivot tables but it will put the interests all in a row along the top regardless if the customer is interested or not and using a record count T/F that means the data sheet in harder to understand then if I leave it as one block and sort by name

Sure I am not alone with this but all searches for the past 2 hrs keep returning pivot/transpose or duplicate items. Any is appreciated

Comment: Are you allowed to write and execute VBA scripts? If so I would chuck the raw data into an array and spit them out when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use VBA, you could first add a column, for instance in column C, with the title "InterestNum."

In C2, just put 1.

In C3, put `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A3) + 1`.  This will find the number interest it is for the person.

Make a lookup column, for instance in column D.  In D2, put `=A2&C2`

Then, make a list of all the people.  I assume that you put this list starting in cell A2 of a new sheet.  Then put headers starting in B1 so that B1 contains the title "1" and C1 contains the title "2" standing for the interest number and as many columns as you wish.

Then in Cell B2, put the formula `=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A2&B$1,data!$D$2:$D$5,0)),"",INDEX(data!$B$2:$B$5,MATCH($A2&B$1,data!$D$2:$D$5,0)))`

This assumes that your original data is in the `data` tab.  I only tested with 4 rows, so you would need to change `$D$2:$D$5` to have as many rows as you do.  This works by looking up a combination of the name and interest number.  It first checks to see if that combination exists in the data.  If not, it leaves that interest blank.  If so, it finds the actual interest by going to the same row of the lookup.

Comment: HI Many thanks. Unfortunately I can have 140 different interest types and the average customer will only have between 5 -10.....some count in specific columns makes it a little heavy to navigate. If the end user scrolling through the data has a query they can then take the line and copy/paste or they can concatenate into a single value to make it easier to email. Ideally need to take and unknown number of interests and group them only where they have a value. Thanks again

Comment: That generates the output table that you requested in your question.  I am not understanding what your objection to what I provided is.  Are you asking for something different than the output table from your question?

Comment: Hi
That would work a treat for a few smaller datasets I have but I assume when you say create a column for each interest, that would mean since I have 140 interests that's 140 columns and I will get a binary 1 under that column header.

This means to navigate I will have to scroll 140 columns right...please correct me if I have misunderstood.

I am after the actual text value only not count.

thanks Again

Comment: Have you even tried this?  It won't do what you're saying.  There are no binary 1s in this approach.

Comment: I think I may have found the source of your confusion and edited the answer to make it a bit more clear.  I do encourage you to try this approach as I believe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks. I will ignore the "Good Samaritan" that read it with me and try shortly

Thanks for the patience

Comment: HI

would appear ignoring the "all knowing" {#InsertSarcasm}, with the rewrite of the answer and the solo effort without "Java Script Developer" it worked a treat.

Spot on answer, once again thanks for the patience

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicates using standard excel functionality to prevent having the same interest twice for a person.

Now, you could of course use VBA and perform exactly what you need.
However, I suggest that you use the pivot table.
If your data looks something like this...

[image: raw data]

... just use "Insert | Pivot table" and insert a pivot table to a new worksheet.
Then, configure the columns as follows:

[image: pivot result]

Et voilà, there you have all your interests listed only once and if a person shares an interest, there is a "1".

If you would rather use VBA, just comment and I will edit my answer.

Comment: HI

Many thanks.

I have tried to use pivots but unfortunately I have 140 different interest types and the average customer will only have between 5 -10.....some have more but they are in the minority. This makes the pivot table a bit of a beast to navigate

Thanks again

Comment: @MiloHarvey Oh, I see. Do you have any experience with VBA?

Comment: Limited. I can do HTML, SQL and apex but for some reason cant translate that to VBA. Query based stuff is cool but the rendering in format seems to be my issue