# Two columns of data and transpose-matching column A values to the same line

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I am trying to do nearly exactly what this OP asked:

[Table of data want to group, transpose matching values same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508852/table-of-data-want-to-group-transpose-matching-values-same-line)

Though the answers only tally how many cases of each Column A item there is. I'd like to revisit the original ask: I have two columns of data and to explain easier, I'll use names. I have a listing of surnames and family members like this:

```
COLUMN A  COLUMN B
--------- ---------
Jones     Andy
Jones     Karen
Jones     Jimmy
Jones     Robert
Jones     Susie
Thompson  Henry
Thompson  Beth
Patel     Hardeep
Patel     Sneha
Patel     Radha
Patel     Naveen
Healy     Cillian
Healy     Sinead
Healy     Aiden
Smith     Robert
Smith     Mary
Smith     James
Smith     Christine
```

I would like to end up with this - TRANSPOSING the list, then grouping the first names along the row for each family surname.

```
    A         B      C        D        E          F
--------- -------  -------  -------  -------    ------- 
Jones     Andy     Karen    Jimmy    Robert     Susie
Thompson  Henry    Beth
Patel     Hardeep  Sneha    Radha    Naveen 
Healy     Cillian  Sinead   Aiden
Smith     Robert   Mary     James    Christine
```

Like the original poster, I don't know how many family members are in each family. I suppose I could have a maximum family size (like 50) for a looping limit. I also suppose I can loop through the columns using range.offset() to traverse the columns and rows, then do something with the blank rows to clean up afterwards.

I fear that it will be slow. My use case is actually factory part numbers (the surnames) residing in many inventory warehouses (the firstnames). It is true in our system one part number could possibly reside in up to 50 warehouses.

I'm up for any suggestions with the above last name, first name example.

Thanks!
John

Comment: Why not *try to make a start* then post your code if you run into a specific problem?

Comment: I just  helped someone with this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185367/how-to-horizontally-return-looked-up-values-from-duplicates-w-vba-pic/59254703#59254703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `Power Query` available in Excel 2010+

In Excel 2016+ (may be different in earlier versions)

- Data → Get&Transform → From Table/Range
- in the PQ Editor

  - Select Column 1 and `Group Rows`

[image]

---

- Add Custom Column and enter the formula:

---

```
Table.Column([Grouped],"Column2")
```

[image]

---

- Delete the "Table" column
- Click on the double arrow of the "List" column
     -Extract values (use semicolon as a delimiter)
- Split that column by delimiter

And this is what you get:

[image]

---

Here is the "M" Code generated by the above.  You could probably cut/paste this instead of going through the above steps, but you'd have to change the name of the `Table` from `Table5` to whatever it really is.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Column1=text, Column2=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "FirstName", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Column2")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"FirstName", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "FirstName", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"FirstName.1", "FirstName.2", "FirstName.3", "FirstName.4", "FirstName.5"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"FirstName.1", type text}, {"FirstName.2", type text}, {"FirstName.3", type text}, {"FirstName.4", type text}, {"FirstName.5", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: yay... i'm a big fan of power query.  It's fantastic for these kinds of transformations.